# How to declare third party library with dependencies in PLay framework

Tags: dependencies, playframework

I have some custom libraries in my application lib folder which get deleted if I run the **play dependencies --sync** command.

Is there a way to declare the jar files in the application's dependencies.yml so they don't get deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer on [play google group.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/module%2420%242B%2420local/play-framework/tU5OJa5JFhs/itqOik6emgwJ)